# Struct column fails to be store in a Big Query table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, python-polars

###### Description

Hello,

While trying to migrate a part of a code that works with Pandas, I fail to resolve the error below that the code gives me when using a Polars dataframe.

In case of Pandas, I am able to see the results in the destination table.

Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong?

Thank you

###### Error

```py
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Error while reading data, 
error message: 
Schema mismatch: referenced variable 'items.list.item.id_item' has array levels of 1, 
while the corresponding field path to Parquet column has 0 repeated fields; 
reason: invalid, 
message: Error while reading data, 
error message: 
Schema mismatch: referenced variable 'items.list.item.id_item' has array levels of 1, 
while the corresponding field path to Parquet column has 0 repeated fields
```

###### Code

```py
import io
from typing import Dict, List, Union
import pandas as pd
import polars as pl
from google.cloud import bigquery


def append_dataframe_to_table(
    data: Union[pd.DataFrame, pl.DataFrame],
    bq_client: bigquery.Client,
    table_schema: List[Dict[str, str]],
    destination_table: str,
    create_disposition: str,
    write_disposition: str,
    wait_until_finished: bool,
) -> bigquery.LoadJob:
    """
    Append a DataFrame to a BigQuery table.

    :param data: Data to be stored.
    :param table_schema: Intended schema for the target table. Example:
        table_schema = [
        {'name': 'id', 'type': 'INT64', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'},
        {'name': 'full_name', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'REQUIRED'},
        {'name': 'date_of_birth', 'type': 'DATETIME', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'}
        ]
    :param destination_table: Full path of the destination table.
    :param create_disposition: Describes conditions when a job should create a table.
        Possible values:
        |--------------------------------|-------------------------------------------------------------|
        | CREATE_DISPOSITION_UNSPECIFIED | Unknown.                                                    |
        | CREATE_NEVER                   | This job should never create tables.                        |
        | CREATE_IF_NEEDED               | This job should create a table if it doesn't already exist. |

    :param write_disposition: Describes whether a mutation to a table should overwrite or append.
        Possible values:
        |-------------------------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
        | WRITE_DISPOSITION_UNSPECIFIED |   Unknown.                                                      |
        | WRITE_EMPTY                   | This job should only be writing to empty tables.                |
        | WRITE_TRUNCATE                | This job will truncate table data and write from the beginning. |
        | WRITE_APPEND                  | This job will append to a table.                                |

    :param wait_until_finished: If true, wait for the job to finish.
    """
    job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
    job_config.create_disposition = create_disposition
    job_config.write_disposition = write_disposition
    job_config.schema = table_schema

    if isinstance(data, pl.DataFrame):
        job_config.source_format = bigquery.SourceFormat.PARQUET
        # Write DataFrame to stream as parquet file; does not hit disk
        with io.BytesIO() as stream:
            data.write_parquet(stream)
            stream.seek(0)
            load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_file(
                file_obj=stream, destination=destination_table, job_config=job_config
            )
    else:
        load_job = bq_client.load_table_from_dataframe(
            dataframe=data, destination=destination_table, job_config=job_config
        )

    if wait_until_finished:
        print("Waiting for load job to finish.")
        load_job.result()

    return load_job


if __name__ == "__main__":
    table_schema = [
        {"name": "hash", "type": "STRING", "mode": "REQUIRED"},
        {
            "name": "items",
            "type": "RECORD",
            "mode": "REPEATED",
            "fields": [
                {"name": "id_item", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                {"name": "id_category", "type": "INT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
                {"name": "manufacturer", "type": "STRING", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
            ],
        },
        {"name": "prediction", "type": "BOOLEAN", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
        {"name": "confidence", "type": "FLOAT64", "mode": "NULLABLE"},
    ]

    df = pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "hash": ["abcd", "efg"],
            "items": [
                [
                    {"id_item": 1234, "id_category": 12, "manufacturer": "A"},
                    {"id_item": 1235, "id_category": 12, "manufacturer": "B"},
                ],
                [{"id_item": 2345, "id_category": 13, "manufacturer": "C"}],
            ],
            "prediction": [True, False],
            "confidence": [0.4, None],
        }
    )

    bq_client = bigquery.Client(project="my-project")

    append_dataframe_to_table(
        data=df,
        bq_client=bq_client,
        table_schema=table_schema,
        destination_table="my-project.my_dataset.my_test_table",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        wait_until_finished=True,
    )
```

Comment: what does "mode"= "REPEATED" mean? It seems like you  should change that to either NULLABLE or REQUIRED.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor It is used for the nested fields (see the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated) for more info and example)